# Copying array of structs into shared memory

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory

I have multiple processes operating on the same data. I want to keep the data inside shared memory. Problem is it seems I can't save into it (or retrieve).

My whole code for it is here:
https://github.com/kasperekt/LLGame/blob/master/server_src/game_state.c#L74

but it seems that the problem is inside these functions:

```
typedef struct game_state {
  int resources;
  int wins;
  army_t *army;
} game_state_t;

...

static game_state_t *players[2] = { NULL, NULL };
static game_state_t **mem_state = NULL;

...

void attach_state() {
  mem_state = get_memory_data(0);
  players[0] = mem_state[0];
  players[1] = mem_state[1];
}

void save_state() {
  if (mem_state == NULL) {
    mem_state = get_memory_data(0);
  }

  mem_state[0] = players[0];
  mem_state[1] = players[1];
  detach_memory_data(mem_state);
}
```

And example function which works on this data:

```
void increment_resources(int player_id) {
  attach_state();
  const int workers_count = players[player_id]->army->workers;
  players[player_id]->resources += RESOURCES_STEP + (workers_count * 5);
  save_state();
}
```

How I should save it into memory? How does it work? I can't find answer for this.

Maybe this code will also help:

```
game_state_t **get_memory_data(char *shmaddr) {
  const int shmat_flag = 0;
  return shmat(memory_id, shmaddr, shmat_flag);
}

void detach_memory_data(game_state_t **data) {
  if (shmdt(data) == -1) {
    perror("Error detaching memory: ");
    exit(1);
  };
}
```

Comment: `shmat` returns a pointer to shared memory, not a pointer of pointer.

Comment: I think that the main problem in your code is that you are thinking to share pointer through a shared memory between processes.

Your `players` array contains 2 pointer that are allocate by a single process. Those `malloc`ated address are virtualized. You cannot share those "value" between process.

Comment: I will check that. You gave me an idea. Thanks

Comment: I'd also change implementation using `mmap`, on a modern platform, rather than System V functions, for the shared mem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have game_state_t variable. If you are storing multiple states, you only need single dimension array. Here is the sample.

```
game_state_t *memstate;
...
memstate = (game_state_t *) malloc( n * sizeof(game_state_t)); /* alloc memory for n states */

shmptr = shmat(...);

memcpy(shmptr, memstate, size);  /* size for example n * size of(game_state_t)); */
```

OR Simply use only the shared memory.

```
memstate = shmat(...);
```

As indicated in the comments, the pointer members of the structure need to point to the shared memory.

Example;

```
memstate.x = memstate + offset; /* use different offsets based on your usage */
```

Comment: Conceptually right but `game_state_t` struct  has a `army_t *army` member. This address cannot be shared between processes.

Comment: right. I agree. Thx. Some part of shared memory can be used. I think we don't need a heap allocation here. All can be stored in the shared memory itself.